Duplicate records in SQL when a stored procedure is called from a Query M script
I have a SQL Server stored procedure (SP_testSPV01), based on the following query:
INSERT INTO FP_SPV ([CIF Client], [CIF Furnizor], [IDD], [IDE])
    SELECT CIF, CUI, ID_SOLICIT, ID
    FROM OPENQUERY(FB, 'SELECT CIF, ID_SOLICIT, ID, CUI FROM FPRIM WHERE DATAF >= ''2024-07-01''; ')
    WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM FP_SPV WHERE FP_SPV.IDD = ID_SOLICIT);

And I have an Excel file with a table query with following PowerQuery code:
let
    Source = Sql.Database("SRV-DB3\SQLONE", "iScalaDB", [Query="EXEC [dbo].[ SP_testSPV01]"]),
    #"Added Custom" = Table.AddColumn(Source, "Data actualizare SQL", each DateTime.LocalNow()),
    #"Removed Columns" = Table.RemoveColumns(#"Added Custom",{"Records Affected"})
in
    #"Removed Columns"

When I run SP_testSPV01 from Microsoft SSMS, all is fine, but when I refresh table query in Excel, all new records from FP_SPV table are duplicated.
Do you have any idea why this behavior occurs and how I can correct it?

As a side note, the prefix sp_ is reserved, by Microsoft, for Special / System Procedures. It should not be used for User Procedures. Doing so comes with a performance cost and the risk of your Procedure simply not working one day after an update/upgrade. Either use a different prefix or (possibly better) no prefix at all. Is the sp_ prefix still a no-no?

in fact real prefix is Conta. I was edit this for no logical reason :(

Are you certain that FP_SPV doesn't have a column called ID_SOLICIT?

table FPRIM from FireBird have column ID_SOLICIT.
information from column ID_SOLICIT is inserted in table FP_SPV in column IDD
